# set default value of input field based on another field in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular (1.5) I have a form with two input fields:

- ID
- URL

The rules:

- If the ID field is empty then the URL field should be empty
- If the URL field is manually set then it should not change automatically
- Otherwise the URL field should be "http://myurl/"+ID+".txt"

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$watch` on ID Field. If the ID field is changed, the watch function will be called.

```js
$scope.$watch('$scope.ID', function() {
    $scope.url = 'http://myurl/' + $scope.ID + '.txt';
}, true);
```

Comment: i don't think this will work. "If the URL field is manually set then it should not change automatically". Changing ID will overwrite the manually inputted URL

Comment: Agreed, how will this care for not changing the url if it is manually entered?

Answer (score 1):

```
  <input type="text" name="url"
         ng-model="url"
         ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
```

...

```
    function defaulUrl() {
       if $scope.ID {
          return 'http://myurl/'+$scope.ID+'.txt';
       } 

       return ''
    }

    var _url = defaultURl();

    $scope.url = {
       url: function(url) {

            return arguments.length ? (_url= url) : defaulUrl();
       }
    }
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle I made that meets your requirments:[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabs00/r81eh134/)

The code

```
//HTML

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    ID <input type="text" ng-model="data.id" ng-change="onIDChange()"/>
    URL <input type="text" ng-model="data.url" ng-change="onManualUrlChange()"/>
</div>

//JS

angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.data = {
    id:'',
    url:''
  }
  $scope.manualUrl = false;

  $scope.onIDChange = function(){
    if(!$scope.manualUrl){
      if($scope.data.id === ''){
        $scope.data.url = '';
      } else {
        $scope.data.url = "http://myurl/" + $scope.data.id + ".txt";
      }
    }
  }

  $scope.onManualUrlChange = function(){
    $scope.manualUrl = true
  };
}]);
```